# authentication request once for both side

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension, oauth, go

I'm making a chrome extension.

For convenience, I wish to have the user's authorization on chrome side and the server side.

On the browser side, I use chrome.identity.getAuthToken(), and after a prompt I get a token.

If it's possible, how I can reuse this user's authorization on the server side without asking twice for the access?

Comment: Assuming that your connection between chrome and server is encrypted, you can send the generated token to the server and use that value as session on the server until client logs out.

Comment: Once I get the token, how I reuse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found... This is my answer, thank you Minty

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "appengine"
    "appengine/urlfetch"
    oauth "code.google.com/p/goauth2/oauth"
    drive "code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/drive/v2"
)

...

c := appengine.NewContext(r)
transport := &oauth.Transport{
    Token: &oauth.Token{
        AccessToken: "YOUR_TOKEN",
    },
    Transport: &urlfetch.Transport{Context: c},
}
client := transport.Client()
service, err := drive.New(client)
if err != nil {
    // error creating the Drive client
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
result, err2 := service.About.Get().Do()
if err2 != nil {
    http.Error(w, err2.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
}
fmt.Fprintln(w, result.Name)
```